# fancybox in combination with jQuery-Mobile work on desktop-browser but not on mobile device?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, fancybox, overlay

I'm working on a private webpage which shall be used easily on a mobile device (Android, IPhone, etc.) and a desktop-computer - containing some jQuery-PlugIns but nothing extraordinary. I use everywhere the newest available version of each component!

First, fancybox had problems with jQueryMobile out-of-the-box even on a desktop-computer. Due to debug-possibilities on my desktop the problem could be located, analyzed and fixed after some hours.

Afterwards everything seemed fine and I published the project onto the mobile device and recognized that fancybox is behaving strange.

I always get

> The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.

when clicking on a fancyBox-hyperlink.
So I isolated the problem meanwhile: It has to do with jQueryMobile & fancybox.

I published two testpages where you can investigate the layout:

1. a simple **not working** [page](http://www.pixelfinger.de/testfb/test1.html) just with a hyperlink which uses both, jQueryMobile **AND** fancyBox
2. the **same but working** [page](http://www.pixelfinger.de/testfb/test2.html) but without jQueryMobile (only fancyBox)

**The strange thing is that both are working on a desktop computer and different browsers while only the second one is working on my android phone**. Which therefore also makes it impossible to me to debug it (don't know how!).

On the other hand I can't give up jQueryMobile without lossing my mobile device capabilities of my page, can I?

Does anyone know what this problem is about?

Comment: found this one by fluke: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and using the latest JQM build worked
http://jsfiddle.net/PH9qM/show/